# Where do resources reside in HANA cloud platform - SAPUI5 Apps, SAPUI5 library,images etc

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform

I have created a SAPUI5 application using the web-ide in sap HANA cloud platform. I understand that html5 application when created creates a GIT repository but it would be unusable until it is manually initlialized.

I don't see a HANA Repository tab/ section in the web-ide as well. So where actually are all the resources stored?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use the SAP Web IDE for SAP HANA development (XS apps, HANA tables (hdbtable), ...) or the SAP Web IDE for creating SAPUI5 apps?

In the SAP Web IDE for creating SAPUI5 apps your source code is stored in an Eclipse Orion workspace in the cloud, as soon as your app gets deployed to HCP it gets git possiblities, or you can manually initialize it as a git repository as you stated. 
https://help.hana.ondemand.com/webide/frameset.htm?2a11c8d3a9e74ca98861c3db5794042b.html

For SAP HANA Web IDE the code is stored inside a SAP HANA repository, but I don't know any further details.

Comment: Thanks Denise,

I assume when you say SAP Web IDE for HANA development, its the same as development inside the SAP HANA Web-based Development Workbench.
I use the web ide for developing SAPUI5 apps. Is there a way I can see/access this workspace as in any link that takes me to this repository